# django test failed inserting data of fixtures into mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I want to insert test data into database before running my test cases.

From verbose output of django, it said it already loaded a lot of objects from fixtures. However the table still is empty in test database. I set breakpoint in my test code, then check the table of test database. I even debug the django code, it indeed executed the insert sql and return the affected rows. But I still can't find the data in test db!

The database server is mysql.

Any idea for resolving it?

**Verbose output of django test**,

```
...
Loading 'goods_756399566_3my10' fixtures...
...
Trying '/Users/kane/git/blizzard_recommend/blizzard_recommend/src/web/fixtures' for goods_756399566_3my10.xml.zip fixture 'goods_756399566_3my10'...
No xml fixture 'goods_756399566_3my10' in '/Users/kane/git/blizzard_recommend/blizzard_recommend/src/web/fixtures'.
Trying '/Users/kane/git/blizzard_recommend/blizzard_recommend/src/web/fixtures' for goods_756399566_3my10.xml.bz2 fixture 'goods_756399566_3my10'...
No xml fixture 'goods_756399566_3my10' in '/Users/kane/git/blizzard_recommend/blizzard_recommend/src/web/fixtures'.
Trying '/Users/kane/git/blizzard_recommend/blizzard_recommend/src/web/fixtures' for goods_756399566_3my10.json fixture 'goods_756399566_3my10'...
Installing json fixture 'goods_756399566_3my10' from '/Users/kane/git/blizzard_recommend/blizzard_recommend/src/web/fixtures'.
Trying '/Users/kane/git/blizzard_recommend/blizzard_recommend/src/web/fixtures' for goods_756399566_3my10.json.gz fixture 'goods_756399566_3my10'...
No json fixture 'goods_756399566_3my10' in '/Users/kane/git/blizzard_recommend/blizzard_recommend/src/web/fixtures'.
Trying '/Users/kane/git/blizzard_recommend/blizzard_recommend/src/web/fixtures' for goods_756399566_3my10.json.zip fixture 'goods_756399566_3my10'...
...
Installed 117 object(s) from 2 fixture(s)
```

**Update**:

I tried to dump same data as initial_data.json, the data in this fixture can be inserted into test database. I don't know why django failed to insert fixtures before running test cases, but it's a workaround to make my work continue.

**Workaround**:

I'm not sure it's caused by my environment. Anyway I changed the db to SQLLite when doing test, there is no problem to import data of fixtures into memory database. It also make sense to run unit tests without mysql installed.

Comment: Seems to be saying that the file `goods_756399566....` is not found in the given folder. Check the paths?

Comment: @will-hart, below output indicates it's found and installed.

`Trying '/Users/kane/git/blizzard_recommend/blizzard_recommend/src/web/fixtures' for goods_756399566_3my10.json fixture 'goods_756399566_3my10'...
Installing json fixture 'goods_756399566_3my10' from '/Users/kane/git/blizzard_recommend/blizzard_recommend/src/web/fixtures'.`

Comment: Fair enough, I was just looking at this line:   `No xml fixture 'goods_756399566_3my10' in '/Users/kane/git/blizzard_recommend/blizzard_recommend/src/web/fixtures'.`

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but, I found this question while researching a similar problem of my own.  The answer is, every Django test is wrapped in a transaction, so if you're hopping over to some other program to check the database, that's why you can't see it.

This question points to the relevant documentation: [Django Rest Framework testing save POST request data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287012/django-rest-framework-testing-save-post-request-data?rq=1)

(Sadly, this is not the cause of my own problem.)