# Django Restapi - How to test if POST saves data in database?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

So I found this question:
[Django Rest Framework testing save POST request data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287012/django-rest-framework-testing-save-post-request-data)

And I understood that the data created with POST request should be accessible as long as the function is running. So I made the whole test in one function:

```
class PostMovieAPITest(APITestCase):
    def test_correct_request(self):
        title = 'Snatch'
        response = self.client.post('/movies/', data={'title': title}, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        movies = Movie.objects.all()
        self.assertTrue(Movie.objects.get(title=title))
```

The problem is, `Movie.objects.all()` is empty, even though I send a CREATE/POST request in the same function. The API works fine when I do `manage.py runserver' and test it in browser. But how can write a proper test to check if data is actually saved in database?

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from api import views


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'movies', views.MovieViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

views.py:

```
class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        title = request.data.get('title')
        if not title:
            return Response({'Error': "Body should be {'title':'The title of the Movie'}"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        data = get_data_from_omdb(title)

        if len(data) == 0:
            return Response({"Error": "Title does not exist in OMDB database"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        serializer = MovieSerializer(data=data, context={'request': request})

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Show us `urls.py` and `views.py` of `/movies/`

Comment: Urls.py and Views.py added.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that Movie.objects.all() returns an epmty queryset? Because when looking at you code, if first assertion (self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)) passes, the objects should be saved. Also, in terms of testing, as you are creating the object through the api, it is better practice to test that the objects is created through the api, i.e by issuing a retrieve or list request

Comment: You were right, problem solved. Eh. About testing - shouldn't I test POST and GET seperately? And use the most basic and reliable way to test stuff (in this case, model.objects.get())? That's what I thought. But maybe you are right, I would have probably noticed the problem earlier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem thanks to Ozgur Akcali's comment. I couldn't get the movie because Movie object was created based on data from external API, including the title.

"Hire **m**e!" -> "Hire **M**e!"

Sometimes scripting makes me want to kill. Thanks a lot and sorry for wasting your time.

```
def test_correct_request(self):
    title = 'Hire Me!' # was: 'Hire me!'
    response = self.client.post('/movies/', data={'title': title}, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    self.assertTrue(Movie.objects.get(title=title))
```